# Clearing Scrollback When Using tmux on Mac OS Terminal

Tags: osx-lion, tmux

Normally when using Terminal, if I go to View --> Clear Scrollback all previous content in the Terminal app will disappear and the prompt will be available at the top of the screen.  When using Clear Scrollback inside tmux, everything looks the same (including the blinking cursor at the top of the Terminal screen).  However, when I start to type the cursor moves to the bottom line of the screen instead of staying at the top line as you would expect.  As a result, you end up with the prompt on the first line but the text you are typing in "floating" at the bottom in the middle of the screen.  Has anyone seen this before and do you know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tmux command `clear-history` will clear all buffer content that is not shown, so a combination with `ctrl-l` will do the trick. You should not use your terminal's clear scrollback feature as it probably is not aware of tmux running.